# How to install a not listed Extension?

Tags: extension

I want to install extensions which are not listed in the "Add Neww" directory, such as :

- de.systopia.osm-1.2
- net.ourpowerbase.exportpermission-master

I copied those (from their Git source) to my Site Extension directory, but they don't appear in my Extensions list, so, I cant activate them.

How can I activate them ?

Comment: Have you tried hitting the refresh button on the extension page?

Comment: As a tip - rename the folders to `de.systopia.osm` and `net.ourpowerbase.exportpermission`.  Otherwise the folders will have the same names when the extensions are upgraded, which will be confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the documentation from the administrator guide:
https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/extensions/#installing-a-new-extension

There are three steps:

- Upload extension package
- Extract (Unzip) the package
- Install and enable the extension, you should refresh your extensions page to show the new extension.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would be good to add jon's note about renaming extension. also i would recommend 'and then remove the .git file from the extension' to avoid git problems down the track for those using git

Answer (score 2):

The other suggestions are good. If one is a fan of CLI, then [cv](https://github.com/civicrm/cv) provides a few easy options.

**Download a published extension from the directory (long name).**

```
cv dl org.example.foobar
```

**Download a published extension from the directory (short name).**

```
cv dl foobar
```

**Download an unpublished extension (long name and zip URL)**

```
cv dl org.example.foobar@http://example.org/files/foobar-1.2.zip
```

**Download a pre-release (alpha/beta) from the directory.**

```
cv dl --dev foobar
```

Note: By default, all these commands will download to the configured extensions folder, use a sensible subfolder (e.g. `sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.example.foobar`), and refresh the ext list. You can download to an alternate location ( `--to=<absolute-path>`).

Comment: For some reason, the GDPR extension can be found at https://civicrm.org/extensions/gdpr/25 but doesn't show up on the "Admin Extensions" page of my drupal/civi4.7 site (even after refresh). But with `cv dl uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr@https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/archive/v2.5.zip` it's installed with just one command. - Thanks!

Comment: Glad the full URL worked. Note: To show up on the in-app "Admin Extensions" UI for automated download, there's a [Formal Review](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/lifecycle/), and (at time of writing) that extension isn't flagged as reviewed. So you have use the URL or `--dev`

Answer (score 1):

I apologize : I found that I have some jam in my Extension directories : my extensions files are not in the directory specified for (civicrm/ext by default), but in an other (probably to be able to update civicrm without loosing the Extensions).

But, what was unexpected is that refreshing listed this old list while it should have listed an empty list.

I have to put some order in there.